# Can electro-optic amplitude modulator generate sidebands?

Tags: optics

As the phase modulator, can electro-optic amplitude modulator generate sidebands?

I'm really confused now...

Please help me out.

Comment: When you modulate phase, you modulate frequency.  (Exercise:  show that mathematically).   And frequency modulation generates sidebands.

Comment: Yes, an amplitude modulator also generates sidebands.    Can you tell us what you are confused about?

Comment: The spectrum of side bands is very different, so it depends on what you want to do.   Amplitude modulation confines the side bands to a particular band of frequencies (or wavelengths if you prefer).   That's good, for example, for AM radio.  It allows the modulation to be very high, but still stay in the "channel" at the expense of limited bandwidth ... sound quality in the case of radio.   In frequency modulation, the bandwidth (or "channel width") goes up with modulation.  So higher frequencies (better sound quality in FM radio)  is possible, with limitations.  What's the application?

Comment: This is not the place for a tutorial.   But compare the spectra of AM and PM presented [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/radio-frequency-analysis-design/radio-frequency-modulation/amplitude-modulation-theory-time-domain-frequency-domain/) and [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/radio-frequency-analysis-design/radio-frequency-modulation/phase-modulation-theory-time-domain-frequency-domain/).  AM is band limited, PM is not.   Then go on to learn about modulation, perhaps starting with Wikipedia?  I'm sure there are a lot of resources on the Internet.